# Convert String to Drawable

Tags: android

I want to raise a notification showing an icon in the status bar - so far so good, but actually I would like this icon to be a 3 character String.

So my question is: Is there a way to convert my String into a `Drawable` to display it as Icon in the status bar?

EDIT: I recently found an app which does something similar - Battery Indicator

It shows the current battery level as notification icon in the status bar - I wonder if it really uses different 100 images

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: just in case that anybody is interested: I figured out that the application mentioned above really uses one image per value

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Have you found a solution, apart from creating 100 png (for each dpi value) with battery status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short: No, you can't.

Long: The notification needs a `R.drawable.something` for the icon and you can't create it on runtime.

Answer (score 3):

```
   public Drawable getDrawable(String bitmapUrl) {
      try {
        URL url = new URL(bitmapUrl);
        Drawable d =new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream()));
        return d; 
      }
      catch(Exception ex) {return null;}
    }
```

Comment: .setSmallIcon(int) take int as input how will i use drawable there?

Answer (score 2):

you can make your own custom drawable that would work just like the textview widget except it is a drawable instead of a view.  The textview class is just a container for the drawable that contains the text.

Comment: can you please provide at least a draft of code that would do that?

Comment: @vault I don't have a sample, but what you'll want to do is extend Drawable and override draw(Canvas) then just call canvas.drawText() from draw.

Answer (score 1):

I have used a workaround and it worked properly for me.

First i convert the string to bitmap and then convert it to a drawable, here is the code:

```
byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(":",Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);      
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: .setSmallIcon(int) take int as input how will i use drawable there?

Comment: You can only use it on .setLargIcon method which takes a drawable as a parameter, smallIcon only accepts a resource.

Comment: I tried using set setLargIcon But the icon is never visible. when will the large icon get displayed?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the API Demos > App > Notifications > Status Bar?

If you have limited number of String options (like Smileys) you can create drawables for each of those Strings.

Comment: I'd like to avoid that since it's quite a big number of possibilities :)

Answer (score 0):

No you can not, I thought you could use the same method as here: [Combine image and text to drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691818/how-to-create-drawable-containing-image-as-background-and-text-over-it), but you can't, as the notification takes a drawable id, not a drawable object.

Answer (score 0):

(I know this doesn't answer the OP's question fully, but the title got me here since it's pretty general.)

After fiddling around a bit, I've come up with this solution. It's pretty messy and could probably be improved, but it works.

In its current form, the function takes the first letter of the String it's passed and a unique ID for that String. The ID is only used for background color generation and remembering it, so it can be removed if you're going to use a steady color.

I made this to generate default images for contacts that don't have images saved, but it should be easy to adapt. It also happens to return an InputStream instead of a Drawable, but you can either just return `bitmap` after drawing to it, or use `Drawable.createFromStream()`.

```
private static InputStream returnDefaultContact(Context context, String name, long id) {
    Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    textPaint.setTextSize(110);

    int color = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getInt("contact_by_id_" + id, 0);

    if (color == 0) {
        int colorValue1 = (int)((56 + Math.random() * 200));
        int colorValue2 = (int)((56 + Math.random() * 200));
        int colorValue3 = (int)((56 + Math.random() * 200));

        color = Color.rgb(colorValue1, colorValue2, colorValue3);

        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().putInt("contact_by_id_" + id, color).apply();
    }

    Paint backgroundPaint = new Paint();
    backgroundPaint.setColor(color);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(120, 120, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

    canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, backgroundPaint);

    int xPos = (canvas.getWidth() / 2);
    int yPos = (int) ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((textPaint.descent() + textPaint.ascent()) / 2)) ;

    canvas.drawText(name.substring(0, 1), xPos, yPos, textPaint);

    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    byte[] imageInByte = stream.toByteArray();

    return new ByteArrayInputStream(imageInByte);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try  {

    InputStream inputStream = new URL(Your imageWebAddress).openStream();

    drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
    inputStream.close();
  }
  catch (MalformedURLException ex) { }
  catch (IOException ex) { }
  layout.setBackground(drawable);
```