# Creating a SeekBar position popup in Android

Tags: android, seekbar

I have a SeekBar in my application, and I want it to behave so that when the user is dragging the 'thumb', a Popup appears above the thumb (and follows it as the thumb is dragged), and the Popup displays the corresponding positon of the SeekBar (or any other text that position may represent).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found for this popup following the seek bar is to put the textview in a relative layout right above the seekbar. Then, in seekbar's onProgressChange, set the textView's left margin accordingly using

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(widht, height)
params.setLeftMargin(margin)
```

works great, with some tweaking!

cheers

Comment: How did you wind up calculating the Margin?

Comment: there is no setLeftMargin method

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [blog](http://andygardenforever.blogspot.in/2014/04/create-your-own-custom-seek-bar-with.html)

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        p.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, seekBar.getId());
        Rect thumbRect = bar.getSeekBarThumb().getBounds();
        p.setMargins(
        thumbRect.centerX(),0, 0, 0);
        textView.setLayoutParams(p);
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
    }
  });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thumb is a drawable, so a solution could be to set the thumb to a drawable that includes both thumb and popup with text. That means you would need a drawable/icon for each possible value on your slider, and update it every time the value changes. Looking around I found this, which suggests that others have gone that way when they needed text in their drawables: [Convert String to Drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585009/convert-string-to-drawable)

Comment: THat's actually not going to work for my project, because the seek bar corresponds to a position in a book, of which there might be 1000s of different possibilities...

Comment: @Andrew: I see, well, I'm looking forward to see a better answer, it is an interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Kotlin version of the chosen answer and a bit more detail

```
override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
    txtSeekMonthsPopup.text = progress.toString()
    val params: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams = 
    txtSeekMonthsPopup.layoutParams as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
    val existingMargin = params.marginStart
    params.marginStart = (seekBar?.thumb?.bounds?.left?: existingMargin) + 20 // 20 makes the text view more centered on the thumb
}
```