# Seekbar with tooltip android

Tags: android, seekbar

[image]

Hi All,

I am trying to customize android seekbar with tooltip, like the given image.
Is there any way to add the textview with the thumb in seekbar. or any other idea

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We can do it by getting the bounds of thumb. and setting the x of textview in on progressChanged of seekbar

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {

    mDistance.setText("" + AppConstants.getDistance() + " miles");
    //Get the thumb bound and get its left value
    int x = mSeekBar.getThumb().getBounds().left;
             //set the left value to textview x value
    mDistance.setX(x);
}
```

Comment: API level required is 16 or above for implementing this method!

Answer (score 5):

Some optimizations on Bora's (great) answer:

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {

    mDistance.setText("" + AppConstants.getDistance() + " miles");
    float x = seekBarX
            + mSeekBar.getThumb().getBounds().left
            - toolTipTextView.getWidth()/2
            + seekBarLayoutParams.leftMargin;
    mDistance.setX(x);
}
```

and declare:

```
private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams seekBarLayoutParams;
seekBarLayoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) seekbar.getLayoutParams();
//or `LinearLayout` if you're using `LinearLayout`.

private float seekBarX;
int[] location = new int[2];
seekBarX = location[0];
```

This puts it exactly in the middle of the thumb, even if your `SeekBar` has a margin.

Though, it doesn't deal with `Y` position. To solve this, if your `SeekBar` has a `marginTop`, remove it and just add `marginBottom` to the element above it (in xml).

Answer (score 2):

Following calculation worked for me. Pretty simple and logical.

```
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams seekBarParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) seekBar.getLayoutParams();
    // Calculate x position
    float x = seekBarParams.leftMargin + seekBar.getPaddingLeft() + seekBar.getThumb().getBounds().left - tvValue.getWidth()/2;
    tvValue.setX(x);
    // Calculate y position
    float y = seekBarParams.topMargin + seekBar.getPaddingTop() - tvValue.getHeight();
    tvValue.setY(y);
```

Answer (score 1):

It was already asked. They use a TextView for this, you could use a ImageView or a custom View to fit your purpose. [Check here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525731/creating-a-seekbar-position-popup-in-android)