# How to achieve this android Discrete SeekBar design?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-seekbar

[image]

i achieved tooltip design using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396739/seekbar-with-tooltip-android) as reference, now i want to achieved seekbar interval as vertical line and not as dots with numbers as like above the image.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143673/how-to-add-vertical-lines-above-seekbar-in-android

Comment: its looking good but its a workaround i need effective ways to achieve this design

Answer (score 1):

Check this code it may help you

```
public class DWRulerSeekbar extends RelativeLayout implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private int seekbarMinValue = 0;
    private int seekbarMaxValue = 50;

    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private Context context;

    private OnDWSeekBarListener listener;
    private LayoutParams lp;

    public interface OnDWSeekBarListener {
        public void onStopSeekbarValue(double value);
    }

    public DWRulerSeekbar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public DWRulerSeekbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public DWRulerSeekbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }

    public DWRulerSeekbar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        this.context = context;
        init();
    }


    private void init() {

        getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                if (getHeight() > 0) {
                    addCompoenet();
                    getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    private void addCompoenet() {
        removeAllViews();
        LineRulerView lineRulerView = new LineRulerView(context);
        LayoutParams rulerLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, getHeight() / 3 * 2);
        rulerLayoutParams.setMargins(0, 5, 0, 0);
        rulerLayoutParams.addRule(CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        lineRulerView.setLayoutParams(rulerLayoutParams);
        lineRulerView.setMinMaxValue(4, 21);
        lineRulerView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        addView(lineRulerView);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int densityDpi = (int)(metrics.density * 160f);
        seekBar = new SeekBar(context);

        lp = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 60);
        seekBar.setThumb(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green_round_circlebg));


        seekBar.setProgressDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.seekbar));
        seekBar.setProgress(0);
        seekBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        seekBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        seekBar.setLayoutParams(lp);

        seekBar.setMax(15);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
        addView(seekBar);
    }

    public DWRulerSeekbar setDWRulerSeekbarListener(OnDWSeekBarListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
        return this;
    }

    public DWRulerSeekbar setMinMaxValue(int seekbarMinValue, int seekbarMaxValue) {
        this.seekbarMinValue = seekbarMinValue;
        this.seekbarMaxValue = seekbarMaxValue;
        addCompoenet();
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        if (listener != null) {

            listener.onStopSeekbarValue(seekbarMinValue + progress);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
}
```

and in xml you have to add this

```
 <com.xelpmoc.zommodity.customseekbar.DWRulerSeekbar
            android:id="@+id/dwRulerSeekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp">

        </com.xelpmoc.zommodity.customseekbar.DWRulerSeekbar>
```

To get the values from seekbar add this in activity

```
 private void initDWSeekbar() {
        seekbar_ruler = (DWRulerSeekbar) findViewById(R.id.dwRulerSeekbar);
        seekbar_ruler
                .setMinMaxValue((int) MIN_VALUE, (int) MAX_VALUE)
                .setDWRulerSeekbarListener(new DWRulerSeekbar.OnDWSeekBarListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStopSeekbarValue(double value) {
                        timeslorval=value;
                    }
                });
    }
```

seekbar.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:height="5dp" android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seek_bar_background"/>
    <item android:height="5dp"  android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seek_bar_progress" />
</layer-list>
```

and green_round_circlebg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:width="20dp" android:height="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval" >
            <solid android:color="#2CC285"></solid>
            <stroke android:color="#000000" android:width="1dp"></stroke>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```