# RelativeLayout as customise thumb in SeekBar android

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, seekbar

I need to have some dynamic text on thumb in SeekBar is it possible? If someone knows any example that will be great.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create A drawable, with text on it.

Refer to :  [Combine image and text to drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691818/combine-image-and-text-to-drawable)

Then set this drwable dynamically onto seekbar using: setThumb method .

Hope it helps........