# how to set the seek bar thumb with a layout or with a TextView?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, seekbar

i want my seek bar to look like this...[image]

the TextView should move with the thumb of seek bar...
i tried with

seek_needle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    />    
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/seek_needle"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

and in mail.xml

```
  <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
                android:layout_width="349dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:max="202"
                android:layout_weight="80"
                android:thumb="@Layout/seek_needle"                  
                  >         </SeekBar>
```

for this application is crashing
please help me out...

here is logcat output...

```
    09-11 17:50:23.582: I/dalvikvm(4142): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-11 17:50:23.762: I/dalvikvm(4142): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-11 17:50:24.062: I/dalvikvm(4142): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-11 17:50:24.212: I/dalvikvm(4142): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-11 17:50:24.582: I/dalvikvm(4142): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-11 17:50:24.632: I/dalvikvm(4142): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-11 17:50:24.664: D/dalvikvm(4142): GC_CONCURRENT freed 73K, 2% free 9435K/9607K, paused 7ms+8ms
09-11 17:50:24.862: D/AndroidRuntime(4142): Shutting down VM
09-11 17:50:24.872: W/dalvikvm(4142): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.audioscreen/com.example.audioscreen.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.audioscreen/com.example.audioscreen.Fm1Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class android.widget.SeekBar
    09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.audioscreen/com.example.audioscreen.Fm1Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class android.widget.SeekBar
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1797)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:682)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:346)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at com.example.audioscreen.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:82)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     ... 11 more
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #63: Error inflating class android.widget.SeekBar
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at com.example.audioscreen.Fm1Activity.onCreate(Fm1Activity.java:24)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     ... 21 more
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     ... 36 more
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/layout/seek_needle.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f030008
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1923)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
09-11 17:50:24.952: E/AndroidRuntime(4142):     at android.widget.AbsSeekBar.<init>(AbsSeekBar.java:70
09-11 17:50:25.032: D/dalvikvm(4142): GC_CONCURRENT freed 797K, 9% free 9183K/10055K, paused 7ms+7ms
09-11 17:50:25.203: I/dalvikvm(4142): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-11 17:50:25.232: I/dalvikvm(4142): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
09-11 17:50:25.642: I/dalvikvm(4142): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
09-11 17:50:25.662: I/dalvikvm(4142): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722746/add-dynamic-text-over-android-seekbar-thumb - this may help, you can write text in onDraw method

Comment: i also add layout as thumb design but its not working giving error eachtime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method takes a drawable from your resources, draws some text on top of it and returns the new drawable. All you need to do is give it the resource id of your bubble, and the text you want on top. Then you can pass the returned drawable wherever you want it.

```
public BitmapDrawable writeOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text){

    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    Paint paint = new Paint(); 
    paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);  
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
    paint.setTextSize(20); 

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, bm.getHeight()/2, paint);

    return new BitmapDrawable(bm);
}
```

copied from..
[Combine image and text to drawable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691818/combine-image-and-text-to-drawable)

EDIT:

function call looks like this, `mFreqbar.setThumb(writeOnDrawable(R.drawable.fm_radio_tune_position, mytext));`
 I have kept my `fm_radio_tune_position.png` file in `res/drawable/` and '`mytext`' is the string which i want to write on top of that drawable

Comment: that means we do not need any xml file

Comment: Yes, no xml required.

Comment: well @Charan Pai i was trying to implement it but the problem is the text is hiding inside the thumb and if i adjust that via providing different value of y bm.getHeigh()/2 then it gets hidden inside the parent layout above it

Answer (score -1):

The function of the answer translated for who use MonoDroid / Xamarin.Android is the following:

```
public BitmapDrawable WriteOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text)
    {
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, drawableId).Copy(Bitmap.Config.Argb8888, true);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Fill);
        paint.Color = Color.Black;
        paint.TextSize = 20;

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
        canvas.DrawText(text, 0, bm.Height / 2, paint);

        return new BitmapDrawable(bm);
    }
```