# weird Looking seekbar in Android Tablets

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I am working on an APP Which supports both phones and tablets.
Phones it is working fine but when i run the same in 7" tablet the seekbar looks weird ...

can anybody help me with this

[image]

This the custom xml i have used to show the seekbar

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/progress_unselected">

    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/secondary_progress">
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/progress_selected">
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

My seekbar is inside a `RelativeLayout` with `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/SeekBarTestPlay"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip"
    android:max="99"
    android:paddingBottom="10.0dip"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar"
    android:thumb="@drawable/progress_indicator"
    android:thumbOffset="0.0dip" />
```

Comment: Create a custom seekbar of your own try this http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011144/how-to-make-custom-seek-bar-in-android

Comment: can  you post the layout where you add this `Seekbar`?

Comment: @HamidShatu i have given all the details in the last edit

Comment: @Brontok i have used a custom xml for seekbar ...as shown above

Answer (score 0):

You need to make this background nine patch and make dither true. This gives perfect background without break.

```html
 <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <nine-patch xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:src="@drawable/seek"
            android:dither="true" />
</item>
```