# How to add number scale on android SeekBar

Tags: android, android-layout, seekbar

I'm using the out of the box android SeekBar component. Below I would like to add the numbers form 1 to 5 showing the progress of the SeekBar. I have problem distributing the numbers correctly on the seek bar.

Just like the image below

[image: seekbar]

Comment: I think you need something like this http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/androids-seekbar-your-way/943

Comment: I need just to distribute the numbers in the layout, I don't need a listener, the slider stops where I want, I just need to add a number on the place where it stops

Comment: I think you need to create a custom view with seek bar and TextView to achieve what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For drawing text over the seekbar thumb use this function

```
  public BitmapDrawable writeOnDrawable(int drawableId, String text){

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        Paint paint = new Paint(); 
        paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);  
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); 
        paint.setTextSize(20); 
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
        canvas.drawText(text, 0, bm.getHeight()/2, paint);

        return new BitmapDrawable(bm);
    }
```

This function will call as

seekbar.setThumb(writeOnDrawable(R.drawable.thumbimage, mytext));
 put thumbimage.png file in res/drawable/ and 'mytext' is the string which you want to write on top of that drawable

For complete conversation see the below link

[how to set the seek bar thumb with a layout or with a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369519/how-to-set-the-seek-bar-thumb-with-a-layout-or-with-a-textview)

Hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.