# Custom SeekBar with range in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-seekbar

I want to create custom view (seekbar) like this:

[image: Sample custom seekbar]

Thumb should match with text as shown in the image.
Range can vary: it may be between 1-10, 2-8 or 1-15.

Comment: use setProgressDrawable wirh your custom Drawable showing the numbers

Comment: how to show text exactly below thumb.

Comment: create a custom Drawable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15360591/how-to-add-number-scale-on-android-seekbar This may help you :)

Comment: it only drawing text below thumb image ,not showing range like above image

Comment: i want to show range, and thumb must match with range text